# Java 7's multicatch in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In my project, i am using Java 7 along with Java 7's features

[image]

When however i do the following, i see no warning or suggestion that exceptions could be better handled by multi catch block.

[image]

If i go ahead and make a change, IntelliJ does not complain as it shouldn't.

[image]

Additionally, i don't see anything pertaining to this under the Inspections:
[image]

With this 2 questions:

1. How can i enable IntelliJ to recognize these situations and offer to correct them?
2. How can i make sure that upon inspection (Analyze->Inspect code) these types of situations are caught?

Comment: probbaly because they havent gotten around to implementing it yet.
have you tried suggesting it in the issue tracker (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) ? if you ever do please post the link here so people can vote for it

Comment: Features are enabled as shown on http://tv.jetbrains.net/videocontent/java-7-small-language-changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable these features one needs to enable the plugin as shown

[image]

Comment: And how to you install/enable these mentioned plugins?